# Mockito.when stubs being overwritten

Tags: java, mockito

I am trying to stub my mock as follows,

```
when(someMock.someMethod(Matchers.<SomeInterface<MyType>> any()).thenReturn(someValue);
```

and,

```
when(someMock.someMethod(Matchers.<SomeInterface<Map<String,Boolean>>> any()).thenReturn(someOtherValue);
```

I've noticed that the second stub is overwriting the first one. So I get `someOtherValue` even when I call `someMock.someMethod(new SomeInterfaceImplementation());`

I'm not sure what's missing here. I tried looking through Mockito docs for this specific use case but I didn't find anything.

Any help/pointers would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 5):

Because of type erasure, Mockito will not be able to determine at runtime the generic parameter of the instance of `SomeInterface<T>` that is passed to `someMock.someMethod`. Any call to `someMethod` will appear to have been made with an instance of `SomeInterface` with no generic parameter.

The JavaDoc for [Matchers](http://docs.mockito.googlecode.com/hg/latest/org/mockito/Matchers.html) alludes to this problem with a warning (although it does not explain the reason why):

> The any family methods *don't do any type checks*, those are only here to avoid casting in your code. If you want to perform type checks use the isA(Class) method. This might however change (type checks could be added) in a future major release.

There are some other helper methods like [`anyListOf`](http://docs.mockito.googlecode.com/hg/latest/org/mockito/Matchers.html#anyListOf(java.lang.Class)) which seem to deal with the generic parameters of Collections, but again these only exist for convenience, and will not actually check the generic type:

> Generic friendly alias to anyList(). It's an alternative to @SuppressWarnings("unchecked") to keep code clean of compiler warnings.
>
> Any List or null.
>
> This method *don't do any type checks*, it is only there to avoid casting in your code. This might however change (type checks could be added) in a future major release.

Because the `any()` matcher will match any object regardless of type and generic parameters, a second call to `when()` with `any()` will override the first. The only solution for this problem is to call `when(...)` only once for both types of invocation, and to do some kind of runtime inspection to determine what the result should be (for example, in the `Answer` passed to `thenAnswer`).

For example, imagine we want to mock the following class (not really worth mocking, but bear with me):

```
public class SomeClass {
    public <T> T getFirst(List<T> list) {
        return list.get(0);
    }
}
```

The `getFirst` method has the same problem as your class, as using an `any`/`isA`/`anyList`/`anyListOf` matcher would not be able to differentiate between `List<String>` and `List<Integer>`.

Here is one way to mock this with `andAnswer`:

```
@Test
public void testGetFirst() {
    SomeClass mock = mock(SomeClass.class);
    
    when(mock.getFirst(Matchers.<List<?>>any())).thenAnswer(new Answer<Object>() {
        @Override
        public Object answer(InvocationOnMock invocation) {
            List<?> list = (List<?>) invocation.getArguments()[0];

            // Inspect the contents of the list to know which type to return
            Object first = list.get(0);
            if (first instanceof String) {
                return "Z";
            } else if (first instanceof Integer) {
                return 1000;
            } else {
                return null;
            }
        }
    });
    
    String firstString = mock.getFirst(Arrays.asList("A", "B", "C"));
    System.out.println(firstString); // prints Z
    
    Integer firstInteger = mock.getFirst(Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3));
    System.out.println(firstInteger); // prints 1000
}
```

This is pretty ugly, and it may be quite difficult to achieve depending on how your actual generic types are used, but I believe it is the only way to get around the lack of generic type information at runtime.